# My python codes in general are very slow, is this normal?

Tags: python, matlab, performance

I recently began self-learning python, and have been using this language for an online course in algorithms. For some reason, many of my codes I created for this course are very slow (relatively to C/C++ Matlab codes I have created in the past), and I'm starting to worry that I am not using python properly.

Here is a simple python and matlab code to compare their speed.

MATLAB

```
   for i = 1:100000000
        a = 1 + 1
   end
```

Python

```
   for i in list(range(0, 100000000)):
        a=1 + 1
```

The matlab code takes about 0.3 second, and the python code takes about 7 seconds. Is this normal? My python codes for much complex problems are very slow. For example, as a HW assignment, I'm running depth first search on a graph with about 900000 nodes, and this is taking forever. Thank you.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? `range` behaves differently between Py2 and Py3. Also, there is no need to wrap `range` with `list` in this particular instance.

Comment: Also, if the variable i isn't used, you can use _ (underscore) instead of i.

Comment: [Interesting post about DFS in Python](http://eddmann.com/posts/depth-first-search-and-breadth-first-search-in-python/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Performance is [not an explicit design goal of Python](http://python-history.blogspot.nl/2009/01/pythons-design-philosophy.html):

> Don’t fret too much about performance--plan to optimize later when
>   needed.

That's one of the reasons why Python integrated with a lot of high performance calculating backend engines, such as [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/), [OpenBLAS](http://www.openblas.net/) and even [CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/pycuda), just to name a few.

The best way to go foreward if you want to increase performance is to let high-performance libraries do the heavy lifting for you. Optimizing loops within Python (by using xrange instead of range in Python 2.7) won't get you very dramatic results.

Here is a bit of code that compares different approaches:

- Your original `list(range())`
- The suggestes use of `xrange()`
- Leaving the `i` out
- Using numpy to do the addition using numpy array's (vector addition)
- Using CUDA to do vector addition on the GPU

Code:

```
import timeit
import matplotlib.pyplot as mplplt

iter = 100
testcode = [
    "for i in list(range(1000000)): a = 1+1",
    "for i in xrange(1000000): a = 1+1",
    "for _ in xrange(1000000): a = 1+1",
    "import numpy; one = numpy.ones(1000000); a = one+one",
    "import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray; import pycuda.driver as cuda; import pycuda.autoinit; import numpy;" \
    "one_gpu = gpuarray.GPUArray((1000000),numpy.int16); one_gpu.fill(1); a = (one_gpu+one_gpu).get()"
    ]
labels = ["list(range())", "i in xrange()", "_ in xrange()", "numpy", "numpy and CUDA"]

timings = [timeit.timeit(t, number=iter) for t in testcode]

print labels, timings

label_idx = range(len(labels))
mplplt.bar(label_idx, timings)
mplplt.xticks(label_idx, labels)
mplplt.ylabel('Execution time (sec)')
mplplt.title('Timing of integer addition in python 2.7\n(smaller value is better performance)')
mplplt.show()
```

Results (graph) ran on Python 2.7.13 on OSX:
[image: Performance of integer addition in Python]

The reason that Numpy performs faster than the CUDA solution is that the overhead of using CUDA does not beat the efficiency of Python+Numpy. For larger, floating point calculations, CUDA does even better than Numpy.

Note that the Numpy solution performs more that 80 times faster than your original solution. If your timings are correct, this would even be faster than Matlab...

A final note on DFS (Depth-afirst-Search): [here](http://eddmann.com/posts/depth-first-search-and-breadth-first-search-in-python/) is an interesting article on DFS in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `xrange` instead of `range`.

The difference between them is that `**xrange**` generates **the values as you use them** instead of `range`, which tries to generate a static list at runtime.

Comment: Providing he's using Python 2

Comment: Yep. If he's using Python 3 then range should be fine.

Comment: Also, get rid of the `list` call. Forcing the range into a list has overhead as well. Even if they're using Python 3, it will eagerly evaluate the range because of that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, python's amazing flexibility and ease comes at the cost of being slow. And also, for such large values of iteration, I suggest using itertools module as it has faster caching.

The xrange is a good solution however if you want to iterate over dictionaries and such, it's better to use itertools as in that, you can iterate over any type of sequence object.